# Adding a branch in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, git-branch

I'm trying to learn how to use GitHub.
I managed to create a repository and update the master,
But I'm trying to understand how the branching is working.

I have created a new branch on eclipse by right clicking the master and then "Create branch..." button.
After that I double-clicked it to work on this branch, and I added a new class to see if I am working on this branch.

But when I'm going back to the master that class is already there, and I did not used the merge command...
In the project explorer the content on the [...] after the project's name has change to the new branch's name, which I will assumed means that I'm working on a different branch.

So, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before a new item is considered attached to a branch in git, you must commit it. Git works with commits. Branches (and Tags) are only "pointers" to that commits (or "named" commits).

Answer (score 0):

It suggest that you did not change the branch. You worked on the master branch only. You need to switch to a specific branch by going to **Git perspective -> Switch To** option.